# split loaded html into 2 lines

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading in the content from the backend like so:

`<td>{{ data.website_code_integration }}</td>`

and the output is as follows:

```
<script src="127.0.0.1:5000/bot.js" api-key="xxx"></script><div id="bot"></div>
```

what I would like to do is actually split it up so the output looks like this on the page:

```
<script src="127.0.0.1:5000/bot.js" api-key="xxx"></script>
<div id="bot"></div>
```

I have tried this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
     setTimeout(() => {
        let div = document.getElementById('bot');
        if (div) {
           div.style.display = 'block'; 
        }
     }, 1000);
});
```

but it doesn't work. any suggestions?

Comment: What framework/library do you use that allows you to do this `<td>{{ data.website_code_integration }}</td>`?

Comment: Python flask backend and html front-end (jinja2). @Unlucky

Comment: Is `data.website_code_integration` being written to the page as plain text?

Comment: @JosephWebber yes!

Comment: If you can edit the response, did you try adding `\n` for a newline character between the script and div tags?

Comment: @l3l_aze I actually did that, sort of. In python, I ended up creating a helper function that I call which splits everything up. Thanks for the advice!